# No jobs near me, no means to move. What can I do?

Tags: job-search

I studied chemistry at the University of Belgrade and finished with a masters degree. Unfortunately there aren't many job openings near me and my family and me lack the funds for me to move out from them.

I tried applying for teaching positions to start saving money, but I was unable to find someone who would employ me, since I lack the expertise, they say.

With no job in sight and no money to move I find myself trapped in Belgrade, not able to follow my passion and profession.

I tried applying at different universities for a PhD position, but again, no luck.

What I want to ask is, what options do I have left? Ideas or experiences are much appreciated.

#### Update

I tried applying for all sorts of public teaching positions, but was turned down every time.

With family I mean my parents, with whom I still live.

Unfortunately, there isn't a career services office in Belgrade (as far as I know).

I guess I will continue to try and apply for PhD positions and try my hand at landing a private teaching job, although those are hard to find as well.

Is there any advice on where my question might be better placed, if not here?

Comment: The only thing I can share with you is my plan Z, for when everything else fails: flip burgers, clean toilets, whatever you can to get a roof over your head and food on the table. Sad, yes, but sometimes not even a phd and experience will save you :(

Comment: Does the University of Belgrade not have a "career services" department? Universities in the US normally always have people whose job it is to help students find a job. Or talk to your professors?

Comment: You can apply for scholarships and/or paid internships internationally.

Comment: Apply for all kinds of phd scholarships you can find..  all over the world. there are lots of these. If you don't want one, fabio dias plan Z might be your choice

Comment: Not sure what your current financial situation is....  If you think it could be helpful to build up some teaching credentials, you might want to consider teaching young people.  In the U.S. it is often possible to get work as a substitute high school teacher; there is a high demand for STEM.  I think substitute teachers might be called "supply teachers" in the UK.

Comment: Similar to @aparente001's suggestion, have you considered private tutoring? You can set the hours you want to work (to fit in around a Plan Z job perhaps) and probably earn more per hour than a teacher employed in a school would. Once you have more experience, try again with the applications.

Comment: Government work. Industry. Teaching non-universities (primary and secondary school).

Comment: What does family mean? Parents or wife and child?

Comment: Keep healthy and happy and be faithful.